# How to add a button on django admin main template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I need a simple way to add a new button on the top of django admin main page. (Black rectangle).
[image: Djangoadmin]

It should be like: (Enable site) / (Disable site). Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

copy the django admin base.html template (from django>contrib>admin>temapltes>admin) into your_app>templates>admin>base.html.

Add your button to the  section

Comment: Hello Henry. Thanks for your answer. It doesn't work. I have installed [django-admin-interface](https://github.com/fabiocaccamo/django-admin-interface) so I tried to extend my base_site with {% extends "admin_interface:admin/base_site.html" %} using django-apptemplates like the documentation says. but my content not appears.

Comment: It works for me.  Have you included your_app in INSTALLED_APPS before django?

Comment: Yes. But it seems to override the admin_interface anyway